# OperationContext.Current and HttpContext.Current are null in OWIN hosted Web API 2

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api2, owin, operationcontext

I am moving some of WCF services to the Web API.

[OperationContext.Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) is usually used in WCF for logging and staging purposes.

> But i'm seeing HttpContext.Current and OperationContext.Current as
>   null.

I have used a framework which uses OperationContext.Current to get the execution context for the current thread. So if i am opting for other ways, i have to add my custom method to the framework, which i am trying to avoid.

Questions:

- What is the workaround that i can adopt?
- If "adding to framework" is must, what can i use to get the current context?

OWIN startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
         HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
         HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
         listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
         config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "Data",
                model: GetModel()
         );
         config.EnsureInitialized();
         appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

    }
}
```

Startup is called using

`WebApp.Start<Startup>(rootUri);`

CustomFilterAttribute.cs

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var caller = OperationContext.Current; //null
        caller = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; //null
        caller = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity; //desired
    }
}
```

Comment: Got **System.Web** as a ref? Need that alongside **System.Web.MVC**.

Comment: Yes. I have both. My filters are derived from System.Web

Comment: Just an extra check, the namespace on HttpContext is correct? Plus the Owin implementation is referred?

Comment: Otherwise, the thread using HttpContext has to derive from a controller.

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current is what im getting as null in the action filter. Can u tell me what do u mean by "Owin implementation is referred"?

Comment: Update your post with some code. Your post's title says the app is Owin hosted but there are different implementations of that API.

Comment: Added OWIN startup class with its caller and actionFilter.

Comment: Probably a self-hosting issue whereby HttpContext.Current for the Web API is null.  Try grabbing the principle from **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal** or using the action's context **actionContext.RequestContext.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContext**.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity;` and 
`actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity;` both works fine! And do u know what maybe the "selfhosting issue u just referred"?

Comment: It has to do with the idea that Web API REST calls should be stateless (i.e. no server information trapped in a session).  So grabbing the principal through the RequestContext properties isn't the preferred way but grabbing the current thread is more than fine.

Comment: So why does it matter if the API is selfhosted or IIS hosted? the "stateless" concept has to hold in both cases rit?

Comment: Out on thin ice on the last question.  ;-)  IIS hosting probably has a more jacked up palette of offerings that don't exist on other platform surfaces and the API doesn't match those surfaces.  But again....I am guessing.

Comment: Hmm maybe. Found [this article](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/) which talks about new things in web api 2 of our concern :P