# ApiController.User.Identity and System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity gives different user details

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication, ntlm, network-service

I have a OWIN hosted web api which runs as `Network Service` with `WindowsAuthentication` enabled by the following line in Configuration method of OWIN Startup class.

```
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
```

Everything works fine except when i try getting user details, by

- `caller = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();`
  Returns: `AuthenticationType: "Negotiate", Name: "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"`
- `ApiController.User.Identity`
  Returns: `AuthenticationType: "NTLM", Name: "Domain\Username"`

I actually expected the credentials which `ApiController.User.Identity` gave. I'm confused about why i got Different results in both. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var caller = OperationContext.Current; //null
        caller = System.Web.HttpContext.Current; //null
        caller = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity; //desired
        caller = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); //gives account details under which the project is hosted. 
    }
}
```

OWIN startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
         HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
         HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
         listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
         config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "Data",
                model: GetModel()
         );
         config.EnsureInitialized();
         appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

    }
}
```

Comment: The user account under which the Web API project run in IIS is different than the user who logs in to your application and call the API. That is why you are getting different values there. If you want the details about the user who is calling Web API then `ApiController.User.Identity` is the one which you should use.

Comment: Thank you. So what if i want to get those details in the ActionFilter?

Comment: In Action filter you should have access to controllerContext or you can simply do `Request.User.Identity`.

Comment: var caller = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity; this works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly explained here -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302377.aspx

> ASP.NET provides the following principal and identity object
>   implementations:
>
> - **WindowsPrincipal** and
>     **WindowsIdentity** objects represent users who have been
>     authenticated with Windows authentication. With these objects, the
>     role list is automatically obtained from the set of Windows groups to
>     which the Windows user belongs.
>
> **GenericPrincipal** and
>   **GenericIdentity** objects represent users who have been
>   authenticated using Forms authentication or other custom
>   authentication mechanisms. With these objects, the role list is
>   obtained in a custom manner, typically from a database.
>
> **FormsIdentity** and
>   **PassportIdentity** objects represent users who have
>   been authenticated with Forms and Passport authentication
>   respectively.
>
> The following tables illustrate, for a range of IIS authentication
>   settings, the resultant identity that is obtained from each of the
>   variables that maintain an **IPrincipal** and/or
>   **IIdentity** object. The following abbreviations are
>   used in the table:
>
> - **HttpContext** =
>     **HttpContext.Current.User**, which returns an
>     **IPrincipal** object that contains security information
>     for the current Web request. This is the authenticated Web
>     client.
>
> **WindowsIdentity** =
>   **WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()**, which returns the
>   identity of the security context of the currently executing Win32
>   thread.
>
> **Thread** =
>   **Thread.CurrentPrincipal** which returns the principal
>   of the currently executing .NET thread which rides on top of the Win32
>   thread.
>
> **Note**   With IIS 6.0 running on Windows
>   Server 2003, the identity Matrix works except that the Machine\ASPNET
>   identity is replaced with NT Authority\Network Service.

[image]

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is null. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` giving Service acoount details. Thread.CurrentPrincipal is giving required details. Is it good practise to opt thread for details?

Comment: @AjayAradhya - Are you sure that `HttpContext.Current` is null? Probably you got  confused with `HttpContext` property of Controller and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`; `Controller.HttpContext` - controller context will not be available (null) in the constructor. If I'm not wrong, you can try getting the identity name from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: I'm getting `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` as null.

Comment: @AjayAradhya - where exactly are you getting it as null? in ActionFilter?

Comment: yes. in Action Filter. I'm trying to authorize user before letting him access controller methods. So i have to check his claims in the filter. But i'm getting System.Web.HttpContext.Current as null.

Comment: @AjayAradhya - well..that shouldn't be; may be you should post some code. anyways try `filterContext.HttpContext`

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1817377.aspx?From+Web+host+to+Self+host+HttpContext+and+more). He talks about "When the api is self hosted, however, httpcontext.current is null"

Comment: @AjayAradhya - my bad..i missed that you were self hosting the api.

Comment: @AjayAradhya - `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal` should have the principal or there might be a way to get the current context; I remember getting the owin context via some extension method, but couldn't recollect now.

Comment: lool..! started my qtn with "I have a OWIN hosted web api.."

Comment: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity;` and `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as WindowsIdentity;` both work fine! I'm still finding it hard to understand why HttpContext.Current is null in self hosted web api.

Comment: As quoted by @matthew-young in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571499/operationcontext-current-and-httpcontext-current-are-null-in-owin-hosted-web-api?noredirect=1#comment72410642_42571499) question - "It has to do with the idea that Web API REST calls should be stateless (i.e. no server information trapped in a session). So grabbing the principal through the RequestContext properties isn't the preferred way but grabbing the current thread is more than fine."

Comment: check this out - https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/ - _Web API 2 introduced a new RequestContext class that contains a Principal property. This is now the proper location to look for the identity of the caller. This replaces the prior mechanisms of Thread.CurrentPrincipal and/or HttpContext.User. This is also what you would assign to if you are writing code to authenticate the caller in Web API._

Comment: So that `RequestContext` is referred to the one in `System.Web.Http.Controllers` namespace within `HttpActionContext` class right?

Comment: When you self host, you dont have dependency with System.Web or in other words System.Web decoupling is what differentiate Web API from asp.net MVC and the reason why Web Api is self hostable :)